# 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable' when assigning Image variable using 'from PIL import Image'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm receiving this error simply when trying to resize an image (learning Python here). Running Windows 10. bride.jpg is saved in the same dir as my script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elliot\Python\scripts\c6\image_rotate.py", line 2, in <module>
    im = Image("bride.jpg")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is my code. This exact block of code is running just fine on my instructor's machine and I can't figure out why it's not working for me. He's running Ubuntu. Could that be the reason? I've installed PIL on my machine. If someone could explain what I'm not understanding along with how to fix the code, I'd really appreciate it!

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image("bride.jpg")
new_im = im.resize((480,360))
new_im.save("bride.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `Image.open('bride.jpg')`, not `Image('bride.jpg')`.

Comment: Thanks. Would the above code work in any environment? If not, the course material is incorrect & I need to send feedback. Please advise...

Comment: @Elliot yes, see e. g. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html. The Image is a module, not a function or a constructor, as you use it. You have to use the function open() from module Image, like DeepSpace suggested.